# SQL Server Timeout only on production

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, query-timeout

I have an API endpoint that runs a query. For some reason, when I hit the production endpoint the query times out (after 2 minutes) but when I hit the same endpoint locally with my local environment connected to the same production DB the query runs in a couple of seconds. Is there a reason why this might happen?
The issue is definitely not a connectivity issue because when I hit the same endpoint (on prod) with a different token it doesn't timeout. It's only some tokens that timeout on prod (yet when I run it locally connected to my prod DB it runs in a couple of seconds)

Comment: How does the data between prod and your local server compare? Is there more data in production?

Comment: I'm not using my local DB I'm connecting my local web server to the production DB

Comment: @Ronaldo There is no local DB at play here, OP stated "*connected to the same production DB*". Moshe, are there different connection strings at play, particularly between the different tokens?

Comment: No. Both using the same connection string

Comment: Hmm unfortunately this one's leaving my head scratching a little bit. By any chance are you using EF Core or some other ORM that generates the SQL query for you? If so you should try to get a copy of the generated SQL in the slow and fast case. Sometimes ORMs can do cheeky things when generating the SQL code. Other than that, you can review [Slow in the application, fast in SSMS?](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) which is a comprehensive guide on things that can result in *similar* outcomes as what you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your prod environment is setup with AG listener scaled across multi subnet, with such multi subnet setup the intermittent timeouts would happen without [MultiSubnetFailover=True](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#:%7E:text=Always%20specify%20multiSubnetFailover%3DTrue) setting as part of your connection string.

Also, setting appropriate values for [RegisterAllProvidersIP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/create-or-configure-an-availability-group-listener-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#RegisterAllProvidersIP) and [HostRecordTTL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/create-or-configure-an-availability-group-listener-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#HostRecordTTL) will help controlling the default behavior, especially with environments that are setup with multi subnet.

> When RegisterAllProvidersIP = 1, any clients whose connection strings
> do not use MultiSubnetFailover = True, will experience high latency
> connections. This occurs because these clients attempt connections to
> all IPs sequentially. In contrast, if RegisterAllProvidersIP is
> changed to 0, the active IP address is registered in the Client Access
> Point in the WSFC cluster, reducing latency for legacy clients.
> Therefore, if you have legacy clients that need to connect to an
> availability group listener and cannot use the MultiSubnetFailover
> property, we recommend that you change RegisterAllProvidersIP to 0.

Hope this helps and resolves your problem.